# Android - Share RecyclerView + Adapter between multiple Activities

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter, share

I've got a RecyclerView + Adapter implemented in one activity.

I'm making an intent to a second Activity in which I also need to use the same recycler view (with the same paging mechanism and the same data).

I also need the currentPage and other variables to be shared between the 2 activities (so when I'm going back to the previous activity, the recyclerview and adapter will be synchronised with the other activity's changes.

It seems wrong to send all the relevant data via intent extras and then create a new adapter and recycler view for the second activity.

I'm not sure if I can make it all static, but making only some of the variables static seems wrong.. (e.g MainActivity.currentPage).

How would you've implemented it? There must be a proper way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Reuse code in several activities is possible with fragments.

Sharing recyclerView across several activities is not a good idea, the better approach is to sync your view as soon as you open new activity.

Divide your app into several layers, you could reuse your business model controller but all view need to be recreated from scratch each time you open new activity.